# Error 404 al refrescar pagina en Angular

Tags: angular, error404

estoy haciendo una tienda web con angular 7 y cuando quiero refrescar la pagina dentro de una ruta children me tira el error 404, solo permite refrescar en la ruta "".
Alguien sabe como se soluciona?
dejo el código de mi routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {path:"", component: PrincipalComponent, children:[
    {path:"", component: InicioComponent},
    {path:"contacto", component: ContactoComponent},
    {path:"tienda", component: TiendaComponent},
    {path:"galeria", component: GaleriaComponent},
    {path:"agregar-obra", component: AgregarObraComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    {path:"login", component: LoginComponent}
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const  APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(Routes);
```

Exporta las rutas como una constante

Comment: Generó las rutas como una clase que de aprovisiona en el `app.module` no necesariamente debe ser una constante. De hecho, el deber ser, el como él lo tiene. No creo que esto resuelva el problema del OP.

Comment: No esto no lo soluciono, sigue igual.